# How to scan a document using printer HP 3015 on fedora14?

Tags: fedora, scanner, scanning, fedora-14

I was able to successfully print a document using HP 3015 printer connected to a fedora14 system locally via usb but I am not able to scan any document using the same. The printer does support scanning when connected to an windows XP machine.

Is there any particular package that I need to download and install for scanner drivers on fedora 14?

Answer (score 1):

you can use XSane Image Scanner

to search for scanners: sane-find-scanner